# Can't add class to parent selector using parent() or closest()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this is incredibly easy but I have been writing and rewriting this function for whole day with no success, hope anyone can help me out.

I have an `<li class="has-children">`, when I click on it, it'll check if `<ul>` tag of this event inside has class `is-hidden`, it'll remove that class, my code work very well.

Now, I want to when click on `<li class="go-back">`, the parent (in this case is `<ul class="sub-menu">` will add `is-hidden` again, but it doesn't work. I've used `console.log` to debug and nothing error. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/597x76p9/8/embedded/result/)

HTML

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li class="has-children">
        <a href="content.html">About</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu is-hidden">
            <li class="go-back"><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Contact Us</a></li>

            <li class="has-children">
                <a href="#">hard goods</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu is-hidden">
                    <li class="go-back"><a href="#">Clothing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Beanies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" >Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>   <!-- end main-menu -->
```

JS

```
//open submenu
$('.has-children').on('click', function(event){
    var selected = $(this);
    if( $('.has-children > ul', selected).hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
        $('> a', this).addClass('selected');
        $('> ul', this).removeClass('is-hidden');
        // selected.addClass('selected').next('ul').removeClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').addClass('moves-out');
    }
});

//submenu items - go back link
$('.go-back').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').addClass('is-hidden').parent('.has-children').parent('ul').removeClass('moves-out');
});
```

Comment: So, if I click on the `li.has-children` once, the `.is-hidden` is removed from the `ul` inside the `li.has-children`. Then I click on the same `li`, and the `.is-hidden`is re-added to the child `ul`? I don't quite get what you're trying to do here

Comment: Can you add a code snippet, so we can help you?

Comment: Yes, it'll be removed to display sub-menu.

Comment: you sure the class isn't being added but your css isn't specific enough to see visible changes? Create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @MoshFeu hi, because this is menu have many redundancy code so I afraid you'll find difficult to read it.

Comment: Can you simplify you code so that only those element are present that we need for this problem. There are several `.has-children`, `.go-back` and `.is-hidden` and I find it difficult to see what you expect to happen.

Comment: I just simplified my code :)

Comment: @danielaKay I just updated my code :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the code actually work.

The problem is that after the code added the class 'is-hidden' in this line `$(this).parent('ul').addClass('is-hidden')...`, this class removed by this line `$('> ul', this).removeClass('is-hidden');`.

When you click on `.go-back` the click event of `.has-children` firing too. 
The key is to add `event.stopPropagation()`

```js
$('.has-children').on('click', function(event){
    var selected = $(this);
    if( $('.has-children > ul', selected).hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
        $('> a', this).addClass('selected');
        $('> ul', this).removeClass('is-hidden');
        // selected.addClass('selected').next('ul').removeClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').addClass('moves-out');
    }
});

//submenu items - go back link
$('.go-back').on('click', function(e){
    event.stopPropagation()
    $(this).parent('ul').addClass('is-hidden');
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">About</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu is-hidden">
            <li class="go-back"><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Contact Us</a></li>

            <li class="has-children">
                <a href="#">hard goods</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu is-hidden">
                    <li class="go-back"><a href="#">Clothing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Beanies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" >Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>   <!-- end main-menu -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I updated my code, can you take a look again. New problem is sub sub-menu can't display.

Comment: I don't see the problem now. Your demo is not the same as the attached code. Do you have a problem now? If not, please mark this answer as accepted answer to help other people,

Comment: Hi, please check your code again. If I click on `hard goods`, it won't remove `is-hidden` class in the sub-menu.

Comment: That's because the `hard goods` is not `.go-back`. If you will add it this class it will add the class `is-hidden`.